# Is there a way to set different post templates for parent posts and child posts in the same post type?

Tags: templates, page-template, template-hierarchy

After taking a look through the questions suggested to possibly have my answer, I still can not seem to find something that I references the post-template php files.

I have two custom post types that I am attempting to combine into a single post-type. I will call the custom post types 'Client' and 'Project'. What I have done is create a 'Clients & Projects' custom post type, and set each one of the 'Clients' to parent and the subsequent 'Projects' to Children within the 'Clients & Projects'.

I have PHP templates created already, and they work fine for each of the post types individually, but I can't figure out how to set one of the templates to load for the 'Clients' (parent-posts) and the other template to load for the 'Projects' (child-posts).

The naming of the files is as follows:

- Clients would be clients_projects_parent.php
- Projects would be clients_projects_child.php

I found this code snippet [here](http://www.matrich.net/blog/wordpress/how-to-automatically-apply-parent-page-template-to-all-sub-pages-in-wordpress.htm), but it did not solve my problem.

```
function switch_page_template() {
    global $post;
    // Checks if current post type is a page, rather than a post
    if (is_page()){
        // Checks if page is parent, if yes, return
        if ($post->post_parent == 0)
            return true;
        else if ($post->post_parent != $post->ID){
            $parent_page_template = get_post_meta($post->post_parent,'_wp_page_template',true);
            $template = TEMPLATEPATH . "/{$parent_page_template}";
            if (file_exists($template)) {
                load_template($template);
                exit;
            }
        }
    }
}

add_action('template_redirect','switch_page_template');
```

My ultimate hope would be for each of the Parent and Child posts to load a different PHP template respectively.

**Update:**

I was tinkering around and tried this:

```
add_action('template_redirect', 'get_template');

function get_template(){
    global $wp;
    global $wp_query;

    if(is_page('client_project') || '0' === $post->post_parent){
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-client_project.php');
    }elseif(is_page('client_project') || $post->post_parent > 0){
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-client_project_child.php');
    }
    else{
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-client_project.php');
    }
}
```

I placed a conditional statement in the templates that I am trying to call/redirect as well that looks like this:

```
global $post;

if ( is_page('client_project') || '0' == $post->post_parent ) {
    echo "<h1>This is a parent page</h1>";
    echo "<p>post parent = " . $post->post_parent . "</p>";

} else {
    echo "<h1>This is a child page</h1>";
    echo "<p>post parent = " . $post->post_parent . "</p>";
}
```

Now, what is happening is when the posts load each one gives the correct indication from the echo loop that was placed in the template files ie. parent post prints *'This is a parent page'* and gives the correct post parent number *'0'*, but the templates are still loading wrong (ether the parent or the child template loads not each one for each type)...

I only tried this after seemingly every other method failed me. I am sure that I am missing something, but I really can't figure it out.

**FINAL UPDATE:**

I finally got the templates to swap out. Although it is in what I can only imagine is the worst possible way. I basically went into the 'parent' template and placed an if statement just before the code of the page. It looks like this:

```
<?php 
    global $post;

    if(is_page('client_project') || $post->post_parent > 0){
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/single-client_project-child.php');
    }
?>
```

I read after I got this to work that TEMPLATEPATH was depreciated, so I will most likely swap that out, but I am going to call this answered, @G. M. if you wanted to, I would really appreciate you writing the correct way to do this, or at the very least a better way. I invite everyone who comes across this question to do the same. Cheeers!

Comment: Is it only me who could not understand exactly what were you trying to explain and what do you want to do.

Comment: 'My ultimate hope would be for each of the Parent and Child posts to load a different PHP template respectively'... How should I accomplish my hope?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way is to use `single_template` filter hook (one of the [`{$type}_template` hooks](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template)).

It is fired by WordPress to filter the template file found for singular post requests.

```
add_filter('single_template', function($template) {

  $queried = get_queried_object();

  if ( $queried->post_type === 'clients_projects' ) { // only for this CPT
    // file name per OP requirements
    $file = 'clients_projects_';
    $file .= $queried->post_parent ? 'child' : 'parent';

    // using `locate_teplate` to be child theme friendly
    return locate_template("{$file}.php") ? : $template;
  }

  return $template;

});
```

### How it works

When you visit an url on a WordPress site, WordPress *translate* that url into a set of query arguments, and trigger a database query using them.

There are different types of query, for a page, for an archive, for a post, and so on. Look at [Conditional Tags page](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags) on Codex, there is an exhaustive description of all the query types.

In your case you need to target **single** query type, because you want to change the template used whn a single CPT is required.

After a query is triggered, WordPress looks into theme folder to find a template to use to display query results. Look at [template hierarchy](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Hierarchy) to understand which file is used to each type of query.

When a file is found, before actually include that file, WordPress filter it using 2 filters.

- [`"{$type}_template"`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/type_template) that is dynamic, and change for every type of query
- [`'template_include'`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/template_include/) that is fired for all templates.

In code above, I used the `'single_template'` filter to change the template WordPress will load, returning a different template from a callback attacched to that filter.

However, that filter is triggered for **every** single request, even for standard posts and other CPTs, so before change the template I checked if current queried post is one of the CPT we want target. To obtain the current queried post I used `[get_queried_object()][6]` that in singular requests returns the post object.

If current post is not of target post type, I just return the file WordPress found, without altering it.

If current post is one of target post type, I *build* the template name looking at the `post_parent` attribute of the post: if the post has a parent I build `'clients_projects_child.php'` if the post has not a parent I return  `'clients_projects_parent.php'`.

Before actually returning the template file, I use [`locate_template`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/locate_template/) to see if in theme (or in child theme) that template file exists or not. If it exists I return it, in this way WordPress instead of loading the default template load the custom template, if the template doesn't exists I return the default template, that is the one WordPress found.

Comment: This definitely looks like it is going to work, and forgive my novice question, but how does it work? I am completely lost. I placed it in the functions.php of my theme folder. I played around with it a bit (meaning that I changed values to see what was being effected), but I can't get it to change the template loading the same file each time. I am sure I am missing some piece of the 'puzzle'. Thanks for your answer, I am sure that it is the right one.